# struct typedef in C. Variable or type?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

So I want to know the differences between these two.

```
struct Record {
    int ID,
    char *name
}Student;


typedef struct Record {
    int ID,
    char *name
}Student;
```

I know that Student in first one is struct variable.
But is Student in second one a variable or just a type name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example with the `typedef`, `Student` is the type name.

With `typedef`, the name of the type appears where the name of a variable would appear if the `typedef` keyword was removed:

```
        int var_name;
typedef int type_name;

        struct SomeType { ... } some_var;
typedef struct SomeType { ... } SomeType;
```

Remember that in C, a `typedef` name is an alias for some other type name, not a new type per se.  When you define the structure type at the same time as the `typedef` name, the formal rules are the type has been defined (e.g. by `struct SomeType { ... }` before the type name is aliassed to that type (e.g. by `typedef struct SomeType { ... } SomeType;`).

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef struct Record { ... } Student;
```

This creates a new type `struct Record` along with a typedef for it named `Student`. `Student` is an alias for `struct Record`. These would be identical variable declarations:

```
struct Record studentRecord;
Student studentRecord;
```

Typically the typedef will be named the same as the struct so that the `struct` keyword can be dropped when declaring variables.

```
typedef struct Record { ... } Record;

Record record;   // Don't need to write "struct Record".
```